# How do I Extract ZIP code from a Website using selenium python

Tags: selenium

I am new to python selenium i want to extract

```html
https://tools.keycdn.com/geo
```

[tools.keycdn.com/geo](https://tools.keycdn.com/geo)

I need to extract only postal code i.e 10080

only zipcode not any other text

and print it out on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **cookies accept button**, so you need to accept that first, and then using `//dt[text()='Postal code']//following-sibling::dd` xpath you can extract the postal code. See below

**Code:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://tools.keycdn.com/geo")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='alert-cookies']"))).click()

postal_code = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//dt[text()='Postal code']//following-sibling::dd"))).text

print(postal_code)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```